# How to decorate objects created by a custom factory using .NET Core DI?

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, decorator, factory, scrutor

Given I have a factory class responsible for constructing instances of a certain service that has constructor parameters that can only be resolved at runtime, is there a way to leverage container-driven decoration?

Consider the following class which relies on a parameter that is only defined at runtime:

```cs
interface IFooService
{
    void DoServicyStuff();
}

class MyFooService : IFooService
{
    public MyFooService(string somePeskyRuntimeArgument)
    {
        this.peskyValue = somePeskyRuntimeArgument;
    }

    public void DoServicyStuff()
    {
        // do some stuff here with the peskyValue...
    }
}
```

Since the value can only be provided at runtime, we need to move away from the constructor injection and into a method-level parameter passing. This is commonly achieved using a factory implementation like this:

```cs
interface IFooServiceFactory
{
    IFooService CreateService(string heyItsNowAMethodLevelPeskyParameter);
}

class FooServiceFactory : IFooServiceFactory
{
    public IFooService CreateService(string heyItsNowAMethodLevelPeskyParameter)
    {
        return new MyFooService(heyItsNowAMethodLevelPeskyParameter);
    }
}
```

While this works fine if the intent is to just abstract away the construction of the service, it poses a challenge to decorate the `IFooService` instance.

For scenarios where no runtime parameter is involved, this can be easily achieved by tapping into the container to provide our service for us. The example below uses the Scrutor library to decorate the interface with a logging decorator implementation:

```cs
class FooServiceFactory : IFooServiceFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public FooServiceFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider
    }

    public IFooService CreateService(string heyItsNowAMethodLevelPeskyParameter)
    {
        return this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredInstance<IFooService>();
    }
}

...

services
    .AddTransient<IFooService, MyFooService>()
    .AddTransient<IFooServiceFactory, FooServiceFactory>()
    .Decorate<IFooService, LoggingFooService>();
```

But since `MyFooService` takes a primitive value as an argument, we cannot rely on `GetRequiredService<T>` to obtain the instance, as it will fail to find "a registration for `string`" when building the concrete class.

Similarly, changing the factory to rely on `ActivatorUtilities`'s `.CreateInstance` or `.CreateFactory` methods will end up creating the objects while completely ignoring the container registrations, thus leaving us without any decorator.

I know I have at least 2 options to decorate the objects manually, namely:

1. Using the factory itself to manually create the decorator:

```cs
    public IFooService CreateService(string heyItsNowAMethodLevelPeskyParameter)
    {
        return new LoggingService(
             new MyFooService(heyItsNowAMethodLevelPeskyParameter));
    }
```

2. Using a *factory decorator* to inject a decorator after the instance is created:

```cs
abstract class FooServiceFactoryDecorator : IFooServiceFactory
{
    private readonly IFooServiceFactory fooServiceFactory;

    protected FooServiceFactory(IFooServiceFactory fooServiceFactory)
    {
        this.fooServiceFactory = fooServiceFactory;
    }

    public virtual IFooService CreateService(string heyItsNowAMethodLevelPeskyParameter)
    {
        return this.fooServiceFactory.CreateService(heyItsNowAMethodLevelPeskyParameter);
    }
}

class LoggingFooServiceFactory : FooServiceFactoryDecorator
{
    private readonly IFooServiceFactory fooServiceFactory;

    public FooServiceFactory(IFooServiceFactory fooServiceFactory)
    {
        this.fooServiceFactory = fooServiceFactory;
    }

    public override IFooService CreateService(string heyItsNowAMethodLevelPeskyParameter)
    {
        return new LoggingFooService(
            this.fooServiceFactory.CreateService(heyItsNowAMethodLevelPeskyParameter));
    }
}

...

services
    .AddTransient<IFooServiceFactory, FooServiceFactory>()
    .Decorate<IFooServiceFactory, LoggingFooServiceFactory>()
```

Neither of these allows me to directly use `.Decorate` on top of the service interface. The first option works but is heavily coupled (meaning I'd have to keep changing it if I want to add other decorators into the mix), while the second version is less coupled, but still forces me to writing *one factory decorator per service decorator* and thus leads into a much more complex solution.

Another pain point is dependencies on the decorators themselves (for example, `ILogger<T>` on the `LoggingFooService`), which I could potentially solve by leveraging `ActivatorUtilities` to create the decorators instead of `new`ing them up manually.

I could also potentially generalize the "factory decorator" so that the decoration function is parameterized and thus the class can be reused, but it is still very convoluted and hard to maintain, while also not providing as good a syntax for consumers to add new decorators.

```cs
class DecoratedFooServiceFactory<TDecorator> : FooServiceFactoryDecorator
    where TDecorator : IFooService
{
    private readonly IFooServiceFactory fooServiceFactory;
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public FooServiceFactory(
        IFooServiceFactory fooServiceFactory, 
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.fooServiceFactory = fooServiceFactory;
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public override IFooService CreateService(string heyItsNowAMethodLevelPeskyParameter)
    {
        return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<TDecorator>(
            this.serviceProvider,
            this.fooServiceFactory.CreateService(heyItsNowAMethodLevelPeskyParameter));
    }
}

...

services
    .AddTransient<IFooServiceFactory, FooServiceFactory>()
    .Decorate<IFooServiceFactory, DecoratedFooServiceFactory<LoggingFooService>>()
```

And finally, if I ever want to move away from using a factory and want to change to using the service directly, this will cause a significant setup change where I'd then have to configure all the decorators again in the container directly instead of just removing the factory registration as one normally would do.

How can I use a factory like this, while still keeping the capability of configuring decorators at the container level using the simple Scrutor syntax?

Comment: Considering you're constructing a service with runtime data, you might want to read [this](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data/).

Comment: Thanks for the link @Steven. The last example you provide, of creating an abstraction to fetch ambient values in place of a direct parameter is nice, but it only works if the source of your value is ambient itself, or static and known at registration time. What if the value is defined by the user on an API call for example? Can you elaborate on how it would be possible to abstract away the value in the constructor in that case? Sure you could hack your way through something like `IHttpContextAccessor` to get to your endpoint's request data, but that would completely bypass MVC binding.

Comment: That's a question I answer in my five-part series on [DI Composition Models](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/compositionmodels/).

Comment: @Steven I had already taken a look at your articles but I did not see any example where the value that needs to be abstracted away came from user input. Can you point me to the particular section that covers this? Again, abstracting ambient values is easy, but when it comes to user input, things are not quite the same (at least in my experience).

Comment: See the eights code sample (which starts with `using (ILifetimeScope scope =`)  in [this article](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/ccm/). It shows how the user name value is set to the `UserName` property of the `ClosureUserContext`. Because this service is scoped, it 'flows' as a closure through the object graph. You can access the value later on.

Comment: @Steven thank you so much for that. I can see how you resolve this now with a scoped value container abstraction by initiating a dependency scope at any arbitrary point of the object graph and then setting the value on the container and using it to resolve a service that depends on the value. Feel free to write it as an answer here and I'll mark your answer as the best one.

Answer (score 2):

###### Ok, a couple of disclaimers first:

1. I agree with [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73227527/how-to-decorate-objects-created-by-a-custom-factory-using-net-core-di#comment129326221_73227527) here in that this looks like an anti-pattern and you will probably be better off redesigning your code to not require run-time values on service construction.
2. I additionally want to caution against using scrutor-like Decorate. While much less confident in this than in the first point, I believe hiding logging in decorators is much less convenient in the long run than it seems at first. Or at least that's what I saw after about a year of trying them out.

###### That said, let's see what can be done.

First, let's put some constraints on where the value is coming from. Specifically, let's say we can have a service providing that value, that looks like this:

```
public interface IValueProvider
{
    string Get();
}
```

This actually allows us to have quite a bit of range. Implementation of that interface can:

- Get value from external API - once or periodically in the background. It can even call it every time Get is called, but this is a very bad idea, as it will make construction asynchronous.
- Get value that is stored in memory and allow some other service to update it. Say, expose a 'configuration' endpoint where a user can set a new value every once in a while.
- Calculate the value based on some algorithm of your choice.

Once you have this service, you can register it like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IValueProvider, AwesomeValueProvider>();
    services.AddSingleton<IFooServiceFactory, FooServiceFactory>(); 
    services.AddTransient<IFooService>(sp => 
    {
        var factory = sp.GetRequiredService<IFooServiceFactory>();
        var valueProvider = sp.GetRequiredService<IValueProvider>();
        return factory.Create(valueProvider.Get());
    });
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: As I mentioned in the OP, the value comes at runtime. I wanted to clarify what I meant by that by saying that it comes from user input: say, a property on a REST API's payload. How would you update the value in that case? Also, what if I have multiple different classes that require a `string` as input? Your `IValueProvider` is too generic and cannot be used for multiple scenarios (unless you meant it just as a toy example name and would suggest a specific interface/implementation pair for each situation.

Comment: As for the feedback on using decorators for logging, I appreciate it but quite strongly disagree: I've been using patterns such as this for several years now with great success. If your classes and abstractions are granular enough (as they should be), using decorators for adding cross-cutting concerns such as logging is absolutely awesome in terms of respecting SRP and OpenClosed principles.

Comment: Lastly, on "this looks like an anti-pattern and you will probably be better off redesigning your code to not require run-time values on service construction.", I'm not convinced this is actually possible in all cases. I've read all of Steven's articles and I'm well aware of how to convert code in most situations to avoid the factory, but in some cases, it is just necessary. I'm open to being proven wrong however. Also, note that even Steven himself says factories are still required sometimes, but they are hidden as an infrastructure concern: you can't just "remove" the need for ctor values.

Comment: @julealgon Do you mean that value comes from the same request, for which this service is needed? Like a GET /{your-string-value} endpoint and in controller for that endpoint you want to use FooService? In which case, it definitely should be a method argument. Otherwise you have a paradox [need value from user request] -> [need controller for user request] -> [need dependencies for controller] -> [need FooService] -> [need value from user request]. It's _possible_ to extract something from the HttpRequest before the controller gets created (via middleware), but it feels like a very bad idea

Comment: @julealgon If decorators work for you, then great :) If you use them extensively, check out [this article](https://medium.com/@nik96a/using-di-with-dispatchproxy-based-decorators-in-c-net-core-ac02f02c5fe5) as well - maybe it will prove more useful to you then me.

Comment: First time I ever heard about `DispatchProxy` (didn't know there was native support for this in the framework itself... always went to Castle proxies for that), so thanks for the link!

Comment: "Do you mean that value comes from the same request, for which this service is needed?" Yes. I mean direct user input for the current operation being performed, where that user input needs to reach a constructor argument in a service (or other component), while that service is also part of dependency injection.